# Unable to add Flurry to iOS 6.0 project

Tags: ios, flurry

The basic error after adding the Flurry Lib while adding the following code in App Delegate

```
[Flurry startSession:@"MY_API_KEY"];
```

is

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[FlurryReachability flurryCurrentReachabilityStatus] in libFlurry_4.2.2.a(libFlurry.a-armv7-master.o)
```

I am posting the App settings image. 
Can you please suggest an answer to the error.

[image: Error Log]

[image: Project Settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the "SystemConfiguration.framework" file to your project.

On the bottom left corner of the "Link Binary with Libraries" section there should be a "+" sign. Click that and type in SystemConfiguration and click on the result then click "add".

Answer (score 0):

You have to add both of these frameworks "SystemConfiguration.framework" And "Security.framework"